# How to specify the ID of a Datasource using Grafana API?

Tags: javascript, meteor, grafana

I want to create DataSource using their API. So I can create DataSource without any problems but I can't specify the id I want to use.

It would be useful for me because I want to create datasource dynamically following this logic:

> check if a new host is up --> if one is up create a datasource
>
> check if a host is down --> if one is down delete his datasource

So to create the datasource I did:

```
createDataSource =  Meteor.bindEnvironment(function() {
  setTimeout(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(){
    HTTP.call("POST", "http://localhost:3000/api/datasources", {
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer 123',
            },
            data: {
                "name":"test_datasource_from_js",
                "id":5,
                "type":"prometheus",
                "url":"http://dataSourceFromJs:9090",
                "access":"proxy",
                "basicAuth":false
            }
        },
        function(error, result) {
            if (!error) {
                console.log(result);
            } else {
                console.error(error);
            }
        });
  }),500);
});
```

But the field `"id":5` had no effect the datasource was created with the id 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set the ID by yourself. Internally Grafana is using a incremental counter in the database to avoid ID collision.

I suggest you work with database names instead of ID.

Comment: Oh okay it's a nice input, so I'll look to do something with the names ! Thank you